# Why does my transform: translate not work on both axes?

Tags: html, css, image, css-transforms

My transform: translate(10px 10px) does not work. When I only put in the value for the x-axis, it works. Also when I use translateX and translateY they do work, but just not both. So I can only translate the images on one axis but never on both. Any ideas?

```css
.gallery {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: calculate(width*66%);
  margin: 10px;
  animation-name: blendin;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transition: ease-in-out all 300ms;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
  transform: translate(10px 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="elbe.jpg" alt="Elbe">
  <img src="tisch.jpg" alt="Tisch">
  <img src="spiegelung.jpg" alt="Spiegelung">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) need a coma in css. So it's not:

```css
transform: translate(10px 10px);
```

but:

```css
transform: translate(10px, 10px);
```

```css
.gallery {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: calculate(width*66%);
  margin: 10px;
  animation-name: blendin;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transition: ease-in-out all 300ms;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="elbe.jpg" alt="Elbe">
  <img src="tisch.jpg" alt="Tisch">
  <img src="spiegelung.jpg" alt="Spiegelung">
</div>
```

Comment: better close such question as typo. A quick lookup to the documentation or a google search would give the answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know and I already flagged it. But who wouldn't want those free points ;)

Comment: you will simply lost them later because such question will get deleted in the near future.